# Webpack 2 + React - nested routes when code splitting with System.import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I have an app that's based of http://moduscreate.com/code-splitting-for-react-router-with-es6-imports/ article. I've added some children routes and now my router config is as such:

```
function errorLoading(err) {
  console.error('Dynamic page loading failed', err);
}

function loadRoute(cb) {
  console.log('load route called');
  return (module) => cb(null, module.default);
}

const obj = {
  component: App,
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('pages/Home')
          .then(loadRoute(cb))
          .catch(errorLoading);
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/gsgs',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('pages/Gsgs')
          .then(loadRoute(cb))
          .catch(errorLoading);
      },
      childRoutes: [
        {
          path: 'go',
          getComponent(location, cb) {
            System.import('pages/Gsgs/Home.js')
              .then(loadRoute(cb))
              .catch(errorLoading);
          },
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('pages/About')
          .then(loadRoute(cb))
          .catch(errorLoading);
      }
    },
  ]
};
```

/index, /about and /gsgs routes trigger dynamic code loading just fine. But /gsgs/go triggers a 404 with

> bundle.js:2 Dynamic page loading failed Error: Loading chunk 0
>   failed.(…)

What am I doing wrong? Im using

> ```
> "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.4",
> "webpack-dev-server": "^2.0.0-beta"
> ```

Comment: not sure why you are getting the error but just to note you can use a JSX element to set up your routes instead of an object that gets unmanageably large.

Comment: Yea I'm aware of the jsx element for router, I find object notation cleaner and easier to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce the issue on the blog post and seems something is wrong. I have tried to fix that and I am not able to see that error any more.

You can refer to this [commit](https://github.com/mihirsoni/react-dynamic-route-loading-es6/commit/65dc7514ac734ec7ddbe62fe4afaec54f289d17e) which has changes against the current master and I am able to load child route dynamically.

Let me know if you face issues again. It would be great if you can have sample repo which can reproduce the issue, I will be glad to debug.

Happy to Help.

Comment: this does seem to solve it. What do you think was the problem?

Comment: So there were couple of issue with existing code.
1) Dependencies  were not updated with webpack2
2) HTML absolute path.
After resolving them and adding child routes it seems to be working fine. If this solves your issue would be great if you can accept this answer.
Thanks.

Comment: It turned out that it was failing because I didn't specify publicPath to be '/'. I think the rest was good. thanks Mihir

Answer (score 0):

Check your config file, (in my case `webpack.config.dev.js` file) and check `publicPath` and set it to `'/'`. Ex : `publicPath: '/'` .

You need to set it in `output` like this

`output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'app.js',
    publicPath: '/',
    /*publicPath: 'http://0.0.0.0:8000/',*/
  }`

I was getting this error

```
   `http://0.0.0.0:8000/0.app.js
    Error: "Loading chunk 0 failed."`
```

and it resolved by changing `publicPath: 'http://0.0.0.0:8000/'` To `publicPath: '/'`.